# How to test GWT/GWTP project?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, gwt, gwt-platform

I am currently building a web application using GWT, GWTP.

And I have some questions about testings:

- Is there a Lint-like tool for GWTP or GWT?
- How to test presenters? ([GWTP with Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/UnitTesting))
- How to test views?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google put out a [great article](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/testing_methodologies_using_gwt.html) about using different testing methodologies with GWT. Definitely check it out. Personally, I use [JUnit](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt_junit.html) when I'm testing back-end stuff like business logic, and [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for testing the UI and application as a whole from the browser's perspective.

Comment: After I asked the question, I found that I can use Mockito for presenter unit test. But I still can't test the view, since I also work with SmartGwt, and it seems I can't create any smartgwt object in the unit test. Could you give me some details about testing with Selenium? Thanks.

Comment: Check out OnGWT's "Selenium" tag @ http://www.ongwt.com/tag/Selenium, lots of good info.

Answer (score 3):

Presenters can be easily unit-tested using [Jukito](http://jukito.arcbees.com/). Here's a quick example of a Presenter being tested using Jukito.

```
@RunWith(JukitoRunner.class)
public class ShowCommentsPresenterTest {
    @Inject
    private ShowCommentsPresenter showCommentsPresenter;

    @Inject
    private PlaceManager placeManager;

    @Test
    public void onReset_PlaceRequestHasNoShowId_ShouldHideView() {
        //given
        when(placeManager.getCurrentPlaceRequest()).thenReturn(new PlaceRequest());

        //when
        showCommentsPresenter.onReset();

        //then 
        verify(showCommentsPresenter.getView()).hide();
    }

    @Test
    public void onReset_PlaceRequestHasAShowId_ShouldDisplayView() {
        //given
        String someShowId = "12345";
        when(placeManager.getCurrentPlaceRequest()).thenReturn(new PlaceRequest()
            .with(ParameterTokens.getShowId(), someShowId));

        //when
        showCommentsPresenter.onReset();

        //then
        verify(showCommentsPresenter.getView()).display();
    }
}
```

In GWTP's philosophy, Views should not be unit-tested directly. Using a dumb View that is a slave to the Presenter, most of the logic can be tested through unit tests on the Presenters. Tools like Selenium are a better fit for testing UI interactivity.